# Problem in printing a webpage containing SVG images in Chromium

Tags: delphi, svg, printing, chromium

I have a html file with the following content:

```
<html>
<body>
<object data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/09/America_Online_logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can check, you can open it with chrome and print it.
But if I use Chromium.Print method, it print empty pages.

Note that this is only a sample. All SVG images had the same problem.

I use Delphi 10.3.2 and CEF4Delphi.

Can any one guide me?

Comment: And you **really really really** mean printing? Not rendering a PDF file?

Comment: Yes. I mean printing (I check it by Microsoft print to pdf and nitro pdf). Using Chromium printtopdf yields the same result, too.

Comment: So, the problem is not related to printtopdf method. It is related to print method, too.

Comment: Simply:
* The web page is shown and printed correctly in browsers (Firefox,Chrome,...)
* The web page is shown correctly but printed empty in Chromium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very likely caused by the [CEF issue #3297](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/3297/printtopdf-does-not-render-iframes) and the workaround described in that report works.

Add this code line before the GlobalCEFApp.StartMainProcess call :

```
GlobalCEFApp.DisableSiteIsolationTrials := True;
```

I tested this workaround with the latest CEF4Delphi version which uses CEF 100.0.14 and the MiniBrowser demo. Your sample HTML is printed correctly with  TChromiumCore.Print and TChromiumCore.PrintToPdf.

Comment: Thank so much. Your solution solved the problem.
But it seems that the DEFAULT value of this flag should me true!

Comment: Chromium enabled the site isolation in Chromium 70 as an extra safety measure against some type of security bugs. 
https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/site-isolation/

CEF implemented that feature in this issue :
https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2498/add-support-for-site-per-process

Disabling the site isolation by default is not recommended.